# Return a pointer while initializing it? C++

Tags: c++

I want to know if it's possible to return a pointer while initializing it. I know that we can use `string s("Hi")` to declare and initialize a `string s`, but can we do the same for a pointer?
What I'm trying to do is keep my code as minimal as possible to try to learn to optimize my code, so I tried `queue<string> *p(&item)` where `item` is a `queue<string>`. This works; however, adding `return` results in the error "Expected primary-expression before *".

My code snippet:

```
struct parsedObj
{
    queue<string> item;
    bool operator!() {return !item.empty();}
    queue<string>* operator*() {return queue<string> *p(&item);}
};
```

Comment: `return &item;`

Comment: You're not optimizing the performance of your code in any way by reducing the amount of characters you type or the number of lines of code it is.   None of that has anything to do with performance.  And from a readability perspective, it often makes it worse.

Comment: Why not return reference?

Comment: Instead of `operator!` I would implement an *explicit* conversion operator `explicit operator bool() {return !item.empty();}`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks!! How come I didn't think of it!

Comment: @xaxxon I'm not optimizing performance I'm just optimizing the way I type. But thanks for your note about readability.

Comment: @Jens Can you please explain how can I use this later on? I don't understand what bool() does.

Comment: @thethiny https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool

Comment: @Jens Thanks! Made everything much easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if it's possible to return a pointer while initializing it

You always initialize the return value. There is no way to not initialize it. (Well, you could forget to write the return statement, but that makes the program ill-formed).

> but can we do the same for a pointer?

Yes.

> adding return results in the error "Expected primary-expression before *".

This limitation applies to non-pointers as well. You cannot write `return string s("Hi")` either for example.

The syntax of return statement is `attr(optional) return expression(optional)`. A declaration is not an expression. `string s("Hi")` and `queue<string> *p(&item)` are declarations.

---

Simply use

```
return &item;
```

to return a pointer. There's no need to declare any variables in that function.

---

PS. It seems quite perverse to return a pointer to a member from the indirection operator. Conventionally the indirection operator does the opposite (i.e. the operand of the indirection is a pointer, and the result is the pointed object).

Comment: "You always initialize the return value. " Look at his code that wasn't what he was trying to do.   He was trying to declare a variable `p` and return it on the same line.

Comment: @xaxxon I've addressed that as well. See the third and fourth paragraph.

Comment: can you give an example of the note you added? Thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: @thethiny consider a pointer for example: `int* ptr = get_pointer(); int value = *ptr;` Note how the indirection operator is applied on a pointer, and the result is the pointed value. That's the opposite of what your indirection operator does.

Answer (score 0):

I used this instead and it did the job better than having a pointer:

```
queue<string>* operator->() {return &item;}
```

This is not the solution, this is just a tip. Now I can use `parsedObj->` which simplifies the process.